# Not getting notified on PagedList updates

Tags: android, kotlin, paging, android-architecture-components

I am using the [PagedList](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/paging/PagedList) library in my app.

It all works as expected, using the [PagedListAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/paging/PagedListAdapter). However, I am not able to find how I can get a callback and be notified that the PagedList has been updated.

At list's [ItemKeyedDataSource](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/paging/ItemKeyedDataSource) is used to fetch the list's data from the network. At that point, the PagedListAdapter's *submitList* is called, providing a PagedList of length 0. When the DataSource has fetched the data from the network, its *callback.onResult()* is executed and the list's UI is updated showing the fetched items. However, this does not call the *submitList* method, and I have not found a way to be notified in the adapter of this update, as the *onCurrentListChanged* is neither called. How can the Adapter be notified of such changes?

Thank you :)

Comment: I kinda need to know more about your DataSource.Factory and the LivePagedListBuilder

Comment: same issue here, please notify if you got any solution.

Comment: you can try step by step with this article https://proandroiddev.com/8-steps-to-implement-paging-library-in-android-d02500f7fffe or the github https://github.com/anitaa1990/PagingLibrary-Sample

Answer (score 1):

You can use `PagedList.addWeakCallback`. You can pass a `PagedList.Callback` to it and listen to events such as `onInserted`, `onChanged` or `onRemoved`. More detail can be found in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56743359/13265590)