# LiveData Paged List size is always 0

Tags: android, android-livedata, android-mvvm, android-paging, android-paging-library

I implemented Paging using android paging library. The ViewModel returns a `LiveData<PagedList<MyObject>>` and I observe that in the fragment where I set the adapter and everything is working good, except that when I want to check the size of the list is always 0.

```
viewModel.getSearchResults().observe(this, mList -> {
           adapter.submitList(mList);
           Log.e("Count", String.valueOf(mList.size()));
       });
```

Where mList is a `PagedList<MyObject>`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you look at [Loading Data](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/paging/PagedList.html#loading-data) from `PagedList` documentation you'll notice the following:

> If you use `LivePagedListBuilder` to get a `LiveData<PagedList>`, it will initialize PagedLists on a background thread for you.

Also, [Mutability and Snapshots](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/paging/PagedList.html#mutability-and-snapshots) states the following:

> A PagedList is mutable while loading, or ready to load from its DataSource. As loads succeed, a mutable PagedList will be updated via Runnables on the main thread. You can listen to these updates with a `PagedList.Callback`. (Note that `PagedListAdapter` will listen to these to signal RecyclerView about the updates/changes).

If you want to listen for the events `onInserted`, `onChanged` or `onRemoved` you can do the following:

```
viewModel.observableData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { pagedList ->
    adapter.submitList(pagedList)
    pagedList.addWeakCallback(null, object: PagedList.Callback() {
        override fun onChanged(position: Int, count: Int) {}
        override fun onInserted(position: Int, count: Int) {
            println("count: $count")
        }
        override fun onRemoved(position: Int, count: Int) {}
    })
})
```

Comment: I don't get any callbacks if the list size is in fact 0. I wanna show a no results message, any suggestions?

Comment: @Ishaan I would go for modelling the datasource to signal no results as separate object, it would be easier to manage: 
Consider sealed class ListItem{
data class Item(val model : Model) : ListItem()
object NoResults: ListItem()
} 

you could pass NoResults if your loadInitial return empty list of items

Comment: This callback returns the pageSizeNumber only , how to return all list number ?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Rxjava3 ,

`RxJava3CallAdapterFactory.create()` ,  default is not synchronous.

You need to use `RxJava3CallAdapterFactory.createSynchronous()`.